# Thinkpad Synaptics Trackpoint: Scrolling suddenly freezes with difficulty to resume

Tags: thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

From time to time vertical scrolling with the Trackpoint stops working. This doesn't cause any error and this is not permanent.

Current bypass possibilities:

- Increase pressure on the stick until it is operative again. The problem is that when it unblocks it scrolls several pages at once.
- Stop vertical scrolling attempt, perform horizontal scrolling, then resume vertical scrolling.

Updating the Synaptics driver is ineffective.

Any solution or explanation?